# Поиск по ключам json в PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, knex.js

Ухх.. Есть данные в базе и один из столбцов содержит json вида

```
{ "Иван": "100 лет",
  "Сергей Николаевич": "25 лет",
  "Сергей": "7 лет",
  "Элеонора Алефтиновна (массаж)": "+7 (654) 985-95-95" }
```

Приходит массив со списком ключей по которым нужно сделать выборку, например

```
const data = ["Сергей", "Элеонора Алефтиновна (массаж)"]
```

knex-ом делаю запрос

```
db.select('*').from('user').whereRaw('?? \\?& ?', ['user_name', data])
```

data - это как раз и есть вот это самый массив с ключами, по которым нужно сделать выборку.

И все хорошо работает. При таком запросе результат будет:

```
{ "Сергей": "7 лет","Элеонора Алефтиновна (массаж)": "+7 985 985 95 95" }
```

А хотелось бы, чтоб еще и "Сергей Николаевич": "25 лет" в это результат записался т.к. имя Сергей, в базе, фигурирует два раза.

Вопрос, как организовать такой/е запрос/ы к БД? Т.е. если ключ содержит два слова и более, а элемент/ы массива, по которому осуществляется выборка, только одно.

Т.е. как-то проверять, имеется ли в ключе данное слово из массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно поменять местами значение и ключа и сделать не строгий поиск!

Comment: Это и есть ответ на вопрос!

Comment: Век живи, век учись...